Excel Conditional Formatting to highlight out of Alphabetical order
I'm attempting to create some conditional formatting that will highlight when column D is not in alphabetical order for a particular page range.
Example:
I have the following output

For page 004 E and F are out of order and Page 005 C and D are out of order. I want these to highlight so I know to fix them.
I'm wondering if there is a function in the formulas that validate something is in alphabetical order. I'm currently unable to find any functions for this but hoping there is or some other way to detect and validate.
I was thinking of using something like
=Countifs(C:C,C2,[Function to validate Col D is in Alphabetical Order])

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Something along the lines of =AND(C3=C2,D3<D2,D3<>"") might work.

Thanks! I'll give this a shot and report back. (Yep that works!! thank you!!! @BigBen)

You were in the right path. Have you tried using this =(CHAR(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)+64)<>D2)*(D2<>"")

Here is another alternative way using COUNTIF() + CHAR()


=(CHAR(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)+64)<>D2)*(D2<>"")



If you want to highlight both rows each time alphabetic order is broken, perhaps a rule based on the following formula, applied to the cells in columns C and D starting in row 2:
=OR(AND($C2=$C3,$D2>$D3,$D3<>""),AND($C2=$C1,$D2<$D1,$D2<>""))


